# Prove the following set of unit vectors is orthogonal.

Tags: linear-algebra, proof-verification, vector-spaces, positive-definite, positive-semidefinite

Suppose   ${v_1 , v_2 ,  ……..v_n}$        are unit vectors in  $\mathbb R^n$   such that $ || v||^2 = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} | <v_i , v>|^2 $ for all $v  \in\mathbb R^n $  Then I have to prove that the set of unit vectors is orthogonal set of vectors .

I have proved it. Can anyone please check if it is okay  or not.

My Attempt::

**EDIT**  : $[v_1 , v_2 , ..... ,v_n]$ are unit vectors in $\mathbb R^n$. Let's say $A$ bea matrix whose rows are the vectors $[v_1 , v_2 , ..... ,v_n]$. Now $||v||^2 = v^tv$ where $v\in \mathbb R^n$ and $\sum |<v_i , v>|^2 = ||Av||^2 = v^tA^tAv$.

$v^tv  $ and $  v^tA^tAv$ are non negative  so $v^tv =  v^tA^tAv$  which implies $v^t(A^tA - I)v = 0 $

So $(A^tA - I)$ is skew symmetric matrix as well as a symmetric matrix so  $(A^tA - I)$is a zero matrix. So $A$  is an orthogonal MatrIX. So the rows are mutually orthogonal and $[v_1 , v_2 , ..... ,v_n]$ is a basis of $\mathbb R^n$.

I have deleted the photo of my attempt I have uploaded here. Instead I wrote my attempt in MathJax.

Comment: I would suggest that you see [this](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) for help with using **MathJax** for typing math.

Comment: -1 for expecting others to read that in stead of taking the time to write it up in MathJAx.

Comment: I write up my attempt . My exam was going on . I was really busy .  That's why I could not make time. I hope you would at least undo your downvote.@Servaes

Comment: I write up my attempt . My exam was going on . I was really busy .  That's why I could not make time. I hope you would at least undo your downvote.@DevashishKaushik

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your proof is right except a minor mistake. In line 6, you should have written$$||Av||^2=v^TA^TAv$$not $$||Av||^2=(v^TA^TAv)^2$$any way, **Your proof is correct and elegant**.

Comment: "$A$ has determinant $1$ and is therefore a rotation matrix": this is simply false. Where does the OP use it?

Comment: Thank you... You are right and i fixed my flaw

Comment: Thank you for checking my answer..I write up my attempt . My exam was going on . I was really busy .  That's why I could not make time. I hope you would at least undo your downvote.@MostafaAyaz

Comment: I didn't downvote at all! Instead I did upvote'

Answer (score 6):

I'm not going to try and decipher that picture. But there is a very easy proof:

Choose one of the unit vectors $v_k$, and set $v=v_k$ in the equation $|| v||^2 = \sum_{i=1}^n \left| \left<v_i , v\right>\right|^2$ (assuming that this is what you meant to write). This gives
\begin{align}
||v_k||^2 & = \sum_{i=1}^n \left| \left<v_i , v_k\right>\right|^2\\
& = ||v_k||^2 + \sum_{i\ne k} \left| \left<v_i , v_k\right>\right|^2
\end{align}

Hence $\sum_{i\ne k} \left| \left<v_i , v_k\right>\right|^2=0$, which means that $v_k$ is orthogonal to every other $v_i$. So the set is orthogonal.

Comment: I write up my attempt . My exam was going on . I was really busy .  That's why I could not make time. I hope you would at least undo your downvote.@TonyK

Comment: I didn't downvote, @cmi. And I am glad that you have made the effort to improve your question!